# How to set the size of Dialog to full screen

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuhIA.png)

> although the size is set to MATCH PARENT but still not getting set to
> extreme full screen ???

```
public class FeedbackDialog extends Dialog {
       
        public FeedbackDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.dialog_electricity_bill);
            getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            //getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
          
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom dialog or with help of dialog fragment.

**Custom Dialog :**

```
      /**
     * show dialog in full screen
     *
     * @param activity reference of activity
     * @param dialog   reference of dialog
     */
    fun fullScreenDialogBounds(activity: Activity, dialog: Dialog?) {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.window != null) {
            dialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(
                ColorDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        activity,
                        android.R.color.transparent
                    )
                )
            )
            dialog.window!!.decorView.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            if (dialog != null) {
                val width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                val height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                dialog.window!!.setLayout(width, height)
            }
            val lp = WindowManager.LayoutParams()
            val window = dialog.window
            lp.copyFrom(window!!.attributes)
            //This makes the dialog take up the full width
            //lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.width = (dialog.context.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.83).toInt()
            //  lp.height = (int) (dialog.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * 0.55);
            window.attributes = lp
        }
    }
```

**Dialog Fragment:**

```
public class FeedbackDialog extends Dialog {
   
    public FeedbackDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         dialog.getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_electricity_bill);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you can use custom dialog in which I'm provide    lp.width = (dialog.context.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.83).toInt() and you can take full screen without 0.83 then dialog show in full screen.